# (root) Additional property environment is not allowed -- Docker compose

Tags: ubuntu, docker-compose, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2, self-hosting

I am deploying photoprism but not able to do it due to this error. I am using Windows machine in which I am using docker through Ubuntu WSL2 terminal. I tried evrything from Syntax to volume mapping and everything. My head is paining rn and tensed by this. I really have to deploy this because my Google Photos storage is finished.

```
version: '3.5'

#This will change the home directory "~" to "/root" in your configuration.

services:
 photoprism:
 # Use photoprism/photoprism:preview instead for testing preview builds:
  image: photoprism/photoprism:latest
  container_name: photoprism
 #Only enable automatic restarts once your installation is properly
 #  configured as it otherwise may get stuck in a restart loop:
 # https://docs.photoprism.org/getting-started/faq/#why-is-photoprism-getting-stuck-in-a-restart-loop
  restart: unless-stopped
  security_opt:
   - seccomp:unconfined
   - apparmor:unconfined
  ports:
   - 2342:2342 # [local port]:[container port]
environment:
 PHOTOPRISM_ADMIN_PASSWORD: "1234"
 PHOTOPRISM_ORIGINALS_LIMIT: 1000
 PHOTOPRISM_HTTP_COMPRESSION: "gzip"
 PHOTOPRISM_DEBUG: "false"
 PHOTOPRISM_PUBLIC: "false"
 PHOTOPRISM_READONLY: "false"
 PHOTOPRISM_EXPERIMENTAL: "false"
 PHOTOPRISM_DISABLE_WEBDAV: "false"
 PHOTOPRISM_DISABLE_SETTINGS: "false"
 PHOTOPRISM_DISABLE_TENSORFLOW: "false"
 PHOTOPRISM_DARKTABLE_PRESETS: "false"
 PHOTOPRISM_DETECT_NSFW: "true"
 PHOTOPRISM_UPLOAD_NSFW: "true"
 PHOTOPRISM_DATABASE_DRIVER: "mysql"
 PHOTOPRISM_DATABASE_SERVER: "mariadb:3306"
 PHOTOPRISM_DATABASE_NAME: "photoprism"
 PHOTOPRISM_DATABASE_USER: "photoprism"
 PHOTOPRISM_DATABASE_PASSWORD: "1234"
 PHOTOPRISM_SITE_URL: "http://localhost:2342/"
 PHOTOPRISM_SITE_TITLE: "PhotoPrism"
 PHOTOPRISM_SITE_CAPTION: "Browse Your Life"
 PHOTOPRISM_SITE_DESCRIPTION:
 PHOTOPRISM_SITE_AUTHOR:
# You may optionally set a user / group id using environment variables if your Docker version or NAS does not
# support this natively (see next example):
# UID: 1000
# GID: 1000
# UMASK: 0000
# Uncomment and edit the following line to set a specific user / group id (native):
# user:"1000:1000"
  volumes:  # Your photo and video files ([local path]:[container path]):
   - "/mnt/c/Users/AmolakJoshi/Pictures:/photoprism/originals"
   - "./storage:/photoprism/storage"

  mariadb:
   image: mariadb:10.5
   container_name: mariadb
   restart: unless-stopped
   security_opt:
     - seccomp:unconfined
     - apparmor:unconfined
   command: mysqld --transaction-isolation=READ-COMMITTED --character-set-server=utf8mb4 --collation-server=utf8mb4
   volumes: # Don't remove permanent storage for index database files!
     - "./database:/var/lib/mysql"

   environment:
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 1234
    MYSQL_DATABASE: photoprism
    MYSQL_USER: photoprism
    MYSOL_PASSWORD: 1234
```